# Broadcast mask operation on array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to improve the performance of a rather simple masking operation on three arrays given the distance of the elements in one of their columns to the same column of a fourth array. All arrays have the same shape.

Can the performance of this operation be improved via broadcasting?

```
# Random data with proper shape
x1, x2, x3, x4 = np.random.uniform(1., 10., (4, 10, 1000))

# This is the operation I' trying to 
dist = 0.01
for x in (x2, x3, x4):
    # Mask of the distance between the column '-6' of x1 versus arrays
    # x2, x3, x4
    msk = abs(x1[-6] - x[-6]) > dist

    # If the distance in this array is larger than the maximum allowed (dist),
    # mask with values from 'x1'.
    x[:, msk] = x1[:, msk]
```

Comment: By performance do you mean memory or speed? I think in either case you're not really going to beat your solution. Performance wise you're only doing a loop over 3 arrays in python so that overhead is going to be negligible compared to the numpy operations. I suspect there is a way to do this using broadcasting, but it's going to involve the creation of a lot of temporary arrays and is not going to be as clear as your code.

Comment: I mean speed. I'm not much concerned about memory usage as the arrays are not that large. The operation is called millions of times so any amount of performance improvement sums to a considerable time saved.

Comment: I get about 15% speedup by replacing assignment with `np.copyto(x, x1, where=msk)`.

Comment: If you replaced `(x2,x3,x4)` with a `(3,4,10,1000)` array you probably could do the replace with one `msk`.  But given the size of the component arrays, I don't think this would save any time.  A few loops involving large arrays is not very expensive.

Comment: @trailing_whitespace I get around 20% speedup with that line, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to broadcasting, I get roughly 10x speedup with numba.

```
np.random.seed(0)
xs = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (4, 10, 1000))
x1, x2, x3, x4 = xs.copy()

from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True)
def modified(xs):
    dist = .01
    for i in range(1, 4):
        for j in range(1000):
            if abs(xs[i, -6, j] - xs[0, -6, j]) > dist:
                for k in range(10):
                    xs[i, k, j] = xs[0, k, j]
```